# How to re-focus and select all on error?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I'd like to help my users that typed incorrect id by setting the focus back on the control they tabbed from and selecting all the text for deletion on the first key hit. This is what I thought would do the trick.

```
Product product = ViewModel.Products
  .FirstOrDefault(item => item.LookUp == ProductCode.Text);
if (product == null)
{
  ProductCode.Focus();
  ProductCode.SelectAll();
  return;
}
...
```

The above is executed when the text box loses the focus. However, it seems that it recurrently calls itself (as the breakpoint gets re-hit all the time) eventually leading to the error very much alike the name of this site.

I also tried to skip re-focusing and only select all the text. However, it appears that the selection of all the text isn't carried out anyway.

How should I do this?

Comment: Is this an event handler code?

Comment: @SimpleVar Yes, it is. I invoke the method using XAML mark-up *LostFocus*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` for textbox which Occurs when the keyboard is no longer focused on this element. Set the `e.Handled = true` for failed validation so that lost focus event does not tunnel down.

```
Product product = ViewModel.Products
  .FirstOrDefault(item => item.LookUp == ProductCode.Text);
if (product == null)
{
  e.Handled = true;
  ProductCode.SelectAll();
  return;
}
...
```

Comment: Very clearly explained and exemplified. +1 for that.